# Silverlight - Is there any way to enable Text selection in Glyphs

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, text

We are using **Glyphs** inside the **Canvas** to display Unicode string.

Is there any way to enable string selection in UI

```
<Canvas Width="793.76" Height="1122.56" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xps/2005/06">
<Glyphs Fill="#ff000000" FontRenderingEmSize="16" StyleSimulations="None" OriginX="75.68" 
 OriginY="90.56" FontUri="/Resources/be908a70-5ed5-43e4-9b83-f1e248a92e83.ttf"
 UnicodeString="Hello XPS World!" />
</Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not an easy way to do this. Most people, when they need to have text that is selectable, use a non-editable TextBox or RichTextBox that has been re-templated to just show the text.